# Jersey 2.x- Inject session scoped component into Resource class returning null

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am little new to Spring and Jersey. I am using Jersey 2.5 with spring 4.2.3.
My issue is that I am not able to inject a session scoped component into Resource. It is not throwing any exception, but initializing the session scoped component as null. However, I am able to get it initialized in another service component.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <version.jdk>1.7</version.jdk>  <!-- 1.7 for JDK 7 -->
        <version.mvn.compiler>3.2</version.mvn.compiler>
        <version.mvn.war.plugin>2.6</version.mvn.war.plugin>
        <version.servlet.api>3.0.1</version.servlet.api>  <!-- use 3.0.1 for Tomcat 7 or Java EE 6 (i.e. Glassfish 3.x) -->
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jersey.version>2.5.1</jersey.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- 2. Bridge logging from JCL to SLF4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3. logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required only when you are using JAX-RS Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mongodb java driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My Session scoped component looks like:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ProfileInfoHolder {

    private Map<String, Object> profileInfo = new HashMap<>();
```

I am trying to inject it into the following Resource class, where I am getting it as null:

```
@Component
@Path("/profile")
public class ProfileResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileResource.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProfileService profileService;

    @Autowired
    private ProfileInfoHolder profileInfoHolder;
```

However, in the below Service class I am able to get the object of ProfileInfoHolder:

```
@Singleton
@Service
public class ProfileServiceImpl implements ProfileService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private ProfileTools profileTools;

    @Autowired
    private ProfileInfoHolder profileHolder;
```

Below is how my web.xml looks like:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ex.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

All the injections are Autowired and doesn't need to be injected manually via applicationContext.xml

Please let me know where I am making the mistake.

Comment: did you finally found a solution?

Comment: No. I changed the approach.